# Returning a list's parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of items and within each list item there is the possibility of sub list items.  I do not have control over this list. It's just what I get.

```
<div id='list'>
<ul>
  <li><span>A</span></li>
  <li><span>B</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Sub 1</span></li>
      <li><span>Sub 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

$('#list').off().on("click","li",function(e){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

What I need is a jQuery event that says when you click on a submenu item I would like to know the parent `li`'s name in the `span`.  So for example if I click "Sub 1" I would like to get "B" as well as "Sub 1."  I can get "Sub 1." That is the easy part. But I don't know how to get "B."  Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**  Right now how this is written is someone clicks any items I get the text in that item.  However, when I click Sub 1 list item I need to know Sub 1 also get the parent list item it came from.  In this case it's B

Comment: Please show your existing code :)

Comment: So where are you stuck?

Comment: _"I would like to know the parent li's name in the span"_. This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I will edit the code to include what I have so far.

Comment: What should be returned if you clicked on `A`?

Comment: like `$(this).closest('ul').prev().text()`

Comment: @j08691: if there is no sub item then nothing but A will be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehting like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Pfzf8/

```
$('ul > li > ul > li').on('click',function(){
    var sub = $(this).children('span').html();
    var parent = $(this).closest('ul').prev().html();
    alert(sub);
    alert(parent);
});

<ul>
  <li><span>A</span></li>
  <li><span>B</span>
    <ul>
      <li><span>Sub 1</span></li>
      <li><span>Sub 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Real real close, I also need to get the A and B if I click on those items.  Sorry i didn't state that above.  I apologize.

Comment: **Edit**: Works great i figured out how to get the top ones.  Thank you very much it was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$('ul > li > ul > li').click(function() {
   console.log($(this).parent().parent().find('span').first().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$("ul li").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation()
   console.log($(this).children("span").text())
   if($(this).parents("li").length !=  0){
       console.log($(this).parents("li").children("span").text())
   }
})
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AXuU9/)